# UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT action not working | ANDROID

Tags: android, installation, shortcut

I am creating shortcut icon manually in my android app. The problem is, it gets duplicated when the app is installed from google play store and launched for the first time (One icon created by google play store and one created by the app).

What I'm trying to do is:

Uninstall the shortcut for the app:

```
private void removeShortcut() {
    try {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "shortcut");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then creating the shortcut for the app:

```
private void createShortcut() {
    try {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "shortcut");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Gave permissions also in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

This permission is no longer supported according to this doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT